# Side menu not working in inner fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have drawerlayout in my application. The file structure is as follows:

```
Class A extends ActionBarActivity
```

Class A contains all code required for implementing Navigation Drawer. I have done that based on the [link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

Side menu contain a list of other options. By default I show a fragment in this activity that is not part of side menu. This particular fragment contains a set of buttons and on click of each I load other fragments.

My issue is: In these inner fragments my side menu is not opening. Should I need to add any settings for that to work?

Looking for reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the logcat says ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. The problem was I was not referring to the same content frame layout in my inner fragments.